# How can i check the customer is confirmed or not before login?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, login, customer-account

How can i check the customer is confirmed or not before login.

this is my login function :

```
public function loginAction() {
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $session = $this->_getSession();
        if (Mage::getSingleton ( 'customer/session' )->isLoggedIn ()) {
            $session->logout ();
        }

        $username = Mage::app ()->getRequest ()->getParam ( 'username' );
      $password = Mage::app ()->getRequest ()->getParam ( 'password' );

        try {
      if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
            if (!$session->login ( $username, $password )) {
                echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error','message'=> $this->__('wrong username or password.')));
                exit;
            } else {

                echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success','message'=>$this->statusAction ()));
                exit;
            }
      }else {
        echo 'bla bla bla';
      }
        } catch ( Mage_Core_Exception $e ) {
            switch ($e->getCode ()) {
                case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED :
                    //$value = Mage::helper ( 'customer' )->getEmailConfirmationUrl ( $username );
                    $message = Mage::helper ( 'customer' )->__ ( 'This account is not confirmed.');
                    echo json_encode ( array (
                            'status' => 'error',
                            'message' =>  $this->__($message )
                    ) );
                    break;
                case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD :
                    $message = $e->getMessage ();
                    echo json_encode ( array (
                            'status' => 'error',
                            'message' => $this->__($message )
                    ) );
                    break;
                default :
                    $message = $e->getMessage ();
                    echo json_encode ( array (
                            'status' => 'error',
                            'message' => $this->__($message )
                    ) );
            }
        }
  }
}
```

iv'e used `$session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()` but it's not working.

**how can i fixe it ?**

Comment: in custom script ?

Comment: yes iv'e create a custom api for my mobile application and when logged in i want to check this customer is activated or not.

Comment: i think in your script you need set login customer after check confirmed one if not confirmed then logout session and send your json

Comment: @PrashantBarot sure, iv'e set login customer after check confirmed and this is my code : `$session->login($username, $password);
    if ($session->getCustomer()->getCustomerActivated()) {
        echo 'confirmed';
    }else {
        echo 'not confirmed';
    }`

Comment: can you just print your session array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just set login customer then check if confirmed look like this :

```
try {
if (!$session->login ( $username, $password )) {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error','message'=> $this->__('wrong username or password.')));
    exit;
  } else {
     if ($session->getCustomer()->getCustomerActivated()) {
         echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success','message'=>$this->statusAction ()));
     }else {
         $array = array();
         $array['status']= 'error';
         $array['message']= 'Please wait for your account to be activated.';
         echo json_encode ($array);
     }
    exit;
}
} catch ( Mage_Core_Exception $e ) {}
```